# My map() callback from Firebase iterates multiple times?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, callback, iteration

I am trying to create a **React.js** component that when loaded, reads data from **Firebase Realtime Database** and iterates it through a `map()` callback function. I'm not quite sure where to put the call for the function. When I placed it under useEffect or in the component before the return, I get too many re-renders or the `map()` is populating infinite number of times.

Does anyone knows why this happens and what can I do?

My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default function X () {
    let [yArray, setYArray] = React.useState([]);
    let [yMap, setYMap] = React.useState(<p>Loading</p>)
    React.useEffect(()=> {
        // y()
    })
    y()
    function y () {
        firebase.database().ref('x').once('value', function (snap) {
            snap.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                yArray.push({
                    name: childSnapshot.key,
                    price: childSnapshot.val().price,
                })
            });
        }).then(
            setYArray(yArray)
        ).then(
            setYMap(yArray => 
                <button>
                    {yArray.name}, {yArray.price}
                </button>
            )
        )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {yMap}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put y() outside effects. Anything outside useEffects will be called on every render.

corrected y()

```
 const [yArray, _setYArray] = React.useState([]);
   
   const yArrayRef = React.useRef(yArray)
   const setYArray = (value) => {
     yArrayRef.current = value;
     _setYArray(value);
   }

React.useEffect(()=> {
    // y()
    y()
     
},[]) //<-- empty array of dependency makes it run only once.

function y () {
        let myArray = yArrayRef.current
        firebase.database().ref('x').once('value', function (snap) {
            snap.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                  myArray.push({
                    name: childSnapshot.key,
                    price: childSnapshot.val().price,
                })
              setYArray(myArray)
       
            });

        })
    }
        const yMap = () => {
           return <button>
                    {yArray.name}, {yArray.price}
                </button>
        }

        return (<div>
            {yMap}
        </div>)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I've tried your solution in multiple versions, but when I use empty array like that, nothing is iterating from the database (yArray stays empty). When I remove the [], it iterates non stop with the values.

Comment: because your y() and all other functions are wrong. corrected codes above.